# jpeg image missed in pdf generated in ios device using jsPDF

Tags: iphone, image, safari, jspdf

When I try below code on ios safari browser and try to generated pdf, it shows empty pdf file instead of showing image.

`var doc = new jsPDF(); doc.setFontSize(40); doc.text("Octonyan loves jsPDF", 35, 25); doc.addImage("examples/images/Octonyan.jpg", "JPEG", 15, 40, 180, 180);`